# Why does my Spring web project not load the correct page on startup?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

Title says it all really. I have a small Spring web project that, on launch, should open `redirect.jsp` in my browser. This should send me through a default controller to `home.jsp`. The problem is, it doesn't. Instead it automatically opens some default index page in my browser. The index page I am shown does not exist in my project, has the title "Starting Page" and only shows a header with "Hello World". Strangely enough, the url in my browser is just `localhost:port/projectrootfolder` and not `localhost:port/projectrootfolder/home.htm` or something similar.

My project structure

```
root  
|...  
|Web pages  
| |WEB-INF  
| | |jsp
| | | |home.jsp    
| |dispatcher-servlet.xml  
| |web.xml  
|redirect.jsp
```

My dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd  
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">    
    <!-- Specify that this dispatcher works with by spring annotations-->   
    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.exevan.ipweb.controller" />        
    <!-- Spring bean that maps url's to controllers -->
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="home.htm">homeController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>    
    <!-- Spring bean that converts logical view name to view location -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
              p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
              p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!-- Index controller -->
    <bean name="homeController"              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
              p:viewName="home" />

    <bean id="conversionService"              class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <list>
                <bean id="dateToStringConverter" class="com.exevan.ipweb.converter.DateToStringConverter"/>
                <bean id="stringToDateConverter" class="com.exevan.ipweb.converter.StringToDateConverter"/>
                <bean id="idToPublisherConverter" class="com.exevan.ipweb.converter.IdToPublisherConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>        
</beans>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My redirect.jsp

```
<%--
Views should be stored under the WEB-INF folder so that
they are not accessible except through controller process.

This JSP is here to provide a redirect to the dispatcher
servlet but should be the only JSP outside of WEB-INF.
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("/home.htm"); %>
```

Comment: Your redirect on myredorect.jsp is home.htm

Comment: It should be /home

Comment: Should be /home as your controller would have the mapping to redirect it to home.jsp

Comment: Changing from /home.htm to /home in redirect.jsp doesn't work. When i run the project it still defaults to some boilerplate index page (which btw doesn't actually exist in my project).

Comment: Are you seeing the tomcat home page

Comment: @LearningPhase no, but the page I am shown does have the Tomcat favicon

Comment: It means that's the default page of the tomcat. Also can you do a search in your workspace for text " hello world" abs see what page it comes on

Comment: I think I am wrong

Comment: It's the default icon for tomcat

Comment: Can you create a chat request and send

Comment: @LearningPhase 1. There are no files containing the words "Hello World!" in my project    
2. I do not know how to send a chat request on Stack Overflow  
3. I do not understand what you want me to send  
4. Please do not spam the comments

Comment: The only way I see is I have a running app in my laptop will post the core for it and you can compare will take about an hour though , if it's ok?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108984/discussion-between-exevan-and-learningphase).

Comment: Can you show your home.jsp?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

Change this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>          <------- Change this
    <url-pattern>/home.htm</url-pattern>  <------- Add this
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>                    
    <welcome-file>/home.htm</welcome-file>   <------- Change this
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Nope, I still get the Hello World page.

Comment: What is home.jsp? is it the page you want to show? you want to show home.jsp or home.html?

Comment: Considering I didn't list a home.html file in my project structure and that such a file doesn't even exist in my project, I'd say its fairly obvious I'm trying to load home.jsp.

Comment: To respond to your edit, I made a mistake in describing my project structure in the question. I did indeed have a /jsp folder in which home.jsp was located. I am also sure I don't need to add an `@RequestMapping` to my controller since I am using a standard Spring controller called `homeController` defined in dispatcher-servlet.xml to process basic page navigation (including navigating to the hme page).

Comment: Sorry didn't see that `ParameterizableViewController` , I update back my answer, try use `/home.htm` instead of `/home`

Comment: Again, didn't help. Still get the same hello world staring back at me.